# Cannot mirror laptop with windows 10 using panasonic smart tv viera

Tags: windows-10, mirroring, smart-tv

What I could do:

- Correctly connected smart tv to Internet;
- Could connect android devices with smart tv;
- Establish a connection between laptop and tv;

When it establishes a connection between laptop and smart tv first appears this image:

[image: First information]

but then my tv says that service is paired off and follow image appears on laptop[image: final screen]

Is this a problem from my Tv model or windows 10?

Comment: Did you try changing display right after you connect?
There should be a button which changes display mode (extended, double, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I tried. The problem is that immediatly after that TV disconnects

Comment: Have you checked that you are using the latest firmware from Panasonic on the TV, as well as the latest drivers & firmware from your WiFi card manufacture on your WiFi card?  I had similar issues with a Samsung and it got better (4-5 min) with firmware on the TV and then worked right after upgrading the laptop (OS patches and all the newest drivers from Intel for my Intel WiFi)